# Problem when set new image in scroll view after zoom

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I use below code for getting zoom image in the scroll view.

- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
  return photo;
  }

but i have problem when i click on next button and set new image it also zoomed.
so it is possible the the next image is normal size. when i click on next button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try reseting the Zoom after the next scroll

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{

   [scrollView zoomToRect:(CGRect)rect animated:(BOOL)animated]
    // or
   [scrollView setZoomScale:(float)scale animated:(BOOL)animated]

}
```